# Grabbing arrays from arbitrary files

Tags: python, arrays, file, python-3.x, file-io

Edited for clarity.

I know we have file IO to access file elements and manipulate them, etc. My question is something I'm curious about.

Let's say that we have a few different files where in each file we can assume that there is only one `list` that contains some data in this `list`.

```
import os
def make_bars(self):
    for files in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
        if files.endswith('.txt'): # or some other file like .py
            a_list = open(files, "r").read()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, so maybe I'm not addressing the question at-hand, but have you looked at `os.walk`?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SOME_ROOT_DIR):
    # root is SOME_ROOT_DIR, then each dir in dirs in turn
    # dirs is a list of all the directories in root
    # files is a list of all files in root
    for filepath in filter(lambda s: s.endswith(".py"), files):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            # do something with the .py file
```

For instance with a directory listing like this:

```
C:\USERS\ADSMITH\TMP\ROOT
│   foobar.txt
│   main.py
│   tasks.py
│
└───subroot
        foo.py
        foobar.txt
```

I could do:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/users/adsmith/tmp/root"):
    print("root is " + root)
    for filepath in files:
        if filepath.endswith('.txt') or filepath.startswith('tasks'):
            print(filepath)

# OUTPUT:  NOTE THE RELATIVE PATHS
root is C:/users/adsmith/tmp/root
foobar.txt
tasks.py
root is C:/users/adsmith/tmp/root\subroot
foobar.txt
```

Comment: I had looked at `os.walk` and considered using it, but os.walk wouldn't grab the absolute path if i remeber correctly so I just opted for the alternative. My question was more so leaning towards whether this is possible if we have everything in `.py` files, and I realize that's rather confusing now. I'm fairly positive your solution and mine works for `.txt` files and other file types in the directory as I haven't run either blocks. However, if we have some arrays defined in some `.py` files is it possible to filter out say a variable name of the array out and just grab the data?

Comment: @Skeletor since you have the root and the relative path, the absolute path is always `os.path.join(root, filepath)`